# combine several queries into one

Tags: sql-server

I would like to be able to query multiple of the same type of argument (for example, several IDs, just to keep the example simple) so I only have to execute a procedure once instead of one time for each individual ID. Where my single-instance proc returns, say, a name, my get-all proc would return a single-column table of names.

What I have now:

```
EXEC MyProc(123);
EXEC MyProc(456);
EXEC MyProc(789);
```

What I would like:

```
// Square brackets aren't correct syntax,
// they just represent a list that contains x number of IDs
EXEC MyProc([123, 456, 789]);
```

Can I do this, and if so, is there an easy mechanism for handling such a thing that doesn't involve cursors and various over-complicated things? Would this even be considered a good idea?

Comment: See [Sommarskog's article on arrays](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)  Table-valued parameters are easy and powerful, XML list arguments tend to have the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the proc only once, you'll have to refactor your proc to work with multiple IDs, as there is no T-SQL function or syntactic sugar to do this for you.

If this is to be varadic in that there may be one or many IDs, you'll have to pass multiple IDs to your proc in one parameter.  This passing of an array of sorts can be easier in more recent versions of SQL Server.

For example, you can try passing:

- [TVPs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) in SQL Server 2008+
- delimited strings that are then split in the proc
- xml which is then parsed in the proc
- a table name which is then read by the proc dynamically
- use a table name which is known by both the proc and the caller beforehand

A quick search for passing arrays is SQL Server will yield more results, among the best of them is [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) as mentioned by @Andomar.